# why need to judge `item == null || empty` in method updateIrem()

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

why need to judge `item == null || empty` in method updateIrem() ?

```
table.setRowFactory(row -> new TableRow<Person>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {

            } else {
                if (item.getFirstName().equals("Jacob")) {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `item == null` is needed to prevent a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

This method is called by the UI when it decides it's necessary to update the item. The `empty` parameter is the way for the UI to tell you whether the cell should be empty or not. See the method's javaDoc:

> We test for the `empty` condition, and if true, we
>   set the text and graphic properties to null. If we do not do this,
>   it is almost guaranteed that end users will see graphical artifacts
>   in cells unexpectedly.

And specifically the `empty` parameter is described as:

> @param empty whether or not this cell represents data from the list. If it
>   is empty, then it does not represent any domain data, but is a cell
>   being used to render an "empty" row.

Why exactly we can't just rely on the fact that `item == null` is the implementation decision of the creators of the component and if you need to know exactly, try to dive in the component's source code.